# ¿Por qué marcar el error al publicar mi aplicación web en IIS?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, iis

espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema ya que no entiendo a que se deba, agradezco su ayuda.

Tengo mi aplicación web en formularios web asp.net cuando la ejecuto en la máquina local funciona perfectamente, pero cuando la publico en el servidor con IIS marca un error como el siguiente:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Por lo que entiendo, se refiere a conexiones abiertas.

Este es mi código donde me marca el error. Estoy trabajando con tres capas en asp.net y visual studio 2008.

El error se genera al ejecutar mi Dataset.

**Código de la capa de acceso a datos.**

```
 private string opcion_cadenaconexion()
    {
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd_Ventas"].ConnectionString;

    }

   private SqlCommand conexion(string commantext, SqlParameter commandparamaters)
    {

        string conexion = opcion_cadenaconexion();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion);          

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commantext, con);               
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(commandparamaters);

           //** Para comprobar que la conexion se cierra lo monitoreo de esta manera donde al ejecutarlo este entra dentro del if
            bool estado = false;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                estado = true;
            }

            return cmd;           
    }

   //** Este es mi dataset donde me marca el error 
   public DataSet ExecuteDataset(string commantext, SqlParameter commandParameter)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = conexion(commantext, commandParameter);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

**Esta es mi clase de entidades**

```
 public  class EUsuario
{

    string usuario;
    string nombre_usuario;
    string puesto;
    string ubicacion;
    string roles;




    public string Usuario
    {
        get { return usuario; }
        set { usuario = value; }
    }


    public string Nombre_usuario
    {
        get { return nombre_usuario; }
        set { nombre_usuario = value; }
    }


    public string Puesto
    {
        get { return puesto; }
        set { puesto = value; }
    }

    public string Ubicacion
    {
        get { return ubicacion; }
        set { ubicacion = value; }
    }      

    public string Roles
    {
        get { return roles; }
        set { roles = value; }
    }
}
```

**Este es el código de Lógico de Negocio**

```
EUsuario uEntidad = new EUsuario();

 public EUsuario Consulta_Datos(string Usuario)
    {
        DataSet datos = new DataSet();
        DataTable datos_usuario = new DataTable();

        SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlparameter.Value = Usuario;            
        datos = _conexion.ExecuteDataset("MenuPermisos", sqlparameter);

        if (datos.Tables.Count > 0 )
            {
                if (datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    datos_usuario = datos.Tables[0];

                    DataRow row = datos_usuario.Rows[0];
                    uEntidad.Usuario = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
                    uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
                    uEntidad.Puesto = Convert.ToString(row[3]);
                    uEntidad.Ubicacion = Convert.ToString(row[4]);
                    uEntidad.Roles = Convert.ToString(row[5]);
                }
                else 
                {
                    uEntidad.Usuario = "";
                    uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = "";
                    uEntidad.Puesto = "";
                    uEntidad.Ubicacion = "";
                    uEntidad.Roles = "";
                }                   

            }

        else
        {

            uEntidad.Usuario = "";
            uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = "";
            uEntidad.Puesto = "";
            uEntidad.Ubicacion = "";
            uEntidad.Roles = "";

        }


        return uEntidad;


    }
```

**Este es el código en la capa de Transacciones**

```
public EUsuario Consultar_Datos(string usuario)
    {
        return conexion.Consulta_Datos(usuario);        
    }
```

**Por ultimo este es mi código en la capa de presentación**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
            EUsuario entidades_usuario = new EUsuario();
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity usuario = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            entidades_usuario = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario.Name);


            if (entidades_usuario.Usuario == "" && entidades_usuario.Nombre_usuario == "" && entidades_usuario.Puesto == "" && entidades_usuario.Ubicacion == "")
            {
                Response.Redirect("redireccionar a una pagina externa",true);
            }

            else
            {
                lblUserWindows.Text = entidades_usuario.Usuario;
                lblNombre_usuario.Text = entidades_usuario.Nombre_usuario;
                lblPuesto.Text = entidades_usuario.Puesto;
                lblUbicacion.Text = entidades_usuario.Ubicacion;

            }


        }
```

Como lo menciones arriba mi error es cuando ejecuto el dataset aunque no entiendo porque me muestra ese error al momento de publicar ya que antes al publicar no me lo mostraba.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con alguna solución?

Comment: ¿En qué momento liberas recursos de la conexión del sql?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx he colocado este codigo dentro de conexion para comprobar el estado de mi conexion y entra en el if por lo que considero se cierra la conexion **bool estado = false;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    estado = true;
                }**

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega ese código donde corresponda :D

Comment: Hola @fredyfx he agregado el código dentro de conexión.

Comment: Por lo que veo, este tutorial te será de utilidad: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=203&inicio=60 a seguir elevando el cosmos con todo el power 2.0! :D

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que la conexión no se cierra nunca y como se queda abierta consume el pool de la conexión

```
finally
{
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Otra podria ser que configures el pool en el string de conexion

Comment: Hola @Betinbeton puedes indicarme donde agrego tu parte de código por favor gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como dije antes, el problema está en que dejas abiertas, inclusive este código:

```
//** Para comprobar que la conexion se cierra lo monitoreo de esta manera donde al ejecutarlo este entra dentro del if
bool estado = false;
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    estado = true;
}

return cmd;
```

Para ser exacto, en esta línea:

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
```

Lo que estás diciendo es: Si el estado de la conexión equivale a conexión cerrada. En ningún lado estás cerrando esa conexión.

Vamos cerrando la conexión luego de su ejecución:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(commandparamaters);
//Aqui te hace falta la ejecución 
conn.Close(); //Ahora cerramos conexión.
```

Para trabajar con conexión a bases de datos, la lógica fundamental es:

1. Abres conexión.
2. Ejecutas comando (query/store procedure).
3. Lees resultado.
4. Cierras conexión.